# Unable to access Grid inside ListBox

Tags: windows-phone-7

Ok so my issue is that I have Grid inside DataTemplate inside ListBox. I need to change the column definitions of the grid when I change the orientation but unfortunately when I assign x:Name to the Grid I cannot access it in the code behind....Is there a specific way to do this? 
I need to set the column definitions of the Grid with name "test".
There is the code:

```
<Grid x:Name="EmployeesGrid" Grid.Row="1" Height="550" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="280"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="195"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <ListBox Height="605" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="test">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="280"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="195"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BranchName}" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: You should be able to access the grid from the code behind using the name `EmployeesGrid`. Are you sure you are in the correct file?

Comment: Is this `Grid` inside each `DataTemplate`?

Comment: I need to access the "test" grid.
Yes it is inside the DataTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
var grid = (Grid)listBox1.FindName("test");
```

If accessing from a tapped event on the `ListBox` use this....

```
var listBox = (ListBox)sender;
var grid = (Grid)listBox.FindName("test");
```

If you want to go one further and get the `TextBlock` from the `Grid` use this....

```
var grid = (Grid)listBox1.FindName("test");
var textBlock = (TextBlock)grid.FindName("textBox's Name")
```

Hope that helps

Comment: var grid = (Grid)listBox1.FindName("test"); 
unfortunately returns null...
I tried to catch the Loading of the Grid event and I did but I don't know how to edit the column width.